# Alternatives to count and know what columns have missing values in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data

I tried this, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to get the information about columns with missing values. For example, I use the target labels to reduce information over missing values and see much better its distribution

```
cols = dataframe.columns.values.tolist()
dfnas = pd.DataFrame()
for col in cols:
    dfnas[col] = dataframe.label[dataframe[col].isnull()].value_counts()
```

[Edited]

This is the result of that snippet

In [6]:

dfnas
Out[6]:

Out[64]:

```
 id f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6
```

0 NaN NaN NaN 180 100 NaN NaN

1 NaN NaN NaN 1 1 NaN NaN

Comment: If the first line of your code is only being used to create a list to iterate over, note that `dataframe.columns` is an Index object (exact type will depend on its values), which is iterable (so you shouldn't need the `.values.tolist()`, just iterate over the index itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `np.sum` to get the counts for each column:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1, np.nan, np.nan], 'c2':[2, 2, np.nan]})
np.sum(df.isnull())
Out[4]: 
c1    2
c2    1
dtype: int64
```